# Need help to build Risk Register in Sharepoint :)

Tags: listview, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3Khp.png)

Hi,

Need to build such a list like on the screenshot in sharepoint with such minimalistic style and color formatting. Could anybody help me with this?

Kind regards,
Ksenia

Comment: Are you using SharePoint-2013?

Answer (score 0):

My test json for your reference:

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,  
  "style": {
    "background-color": "=if(@currentField < 7, 'Green',if(@currentField< 12, 'Yellow',if(@currentField <16, 'Orange','Red')))",
    "color":"white", 
    "margin-bottom":"10px"  
  },
  "children":[
      {
         "elmType":"div",
         "style":{
            "margin-left":"10px"
         },
         "txtContent":"=@currentField"
      }
   ]
}
```

Test result:

[image]